# Is there an identity function that prevents Eigen from evluating a unaryExpr call?

Tags: eigen, template-meta-programming, eigen3

I'm trying to use Eigen in a highly customized implementation of neural networks, and found that my code would be much cleaner if I could assume that there is always an activation function. As far as I can tell, that would just be a call to the `unaryExpr` method of the activation vector. The problem is that I also need to support linear activations, which I can implement either (a) as a completely different code path, or (b) by passing in an identity function to `unaryExpr`, and let the compiler sort out the different code paths.

From the documentation, it looks like the `unaryExpr` method takes a templetized functor, but is there anything I can pass in to suppress what I assume is a pass over the entire vector. I don't see any reason why there *couldn't be*, my question is whether there *is*.

Edit: I'm aware that Eigen does lazy evaluation, and that using `unaryExpr` does not come at a cost until the expression is actually evaluated. My question is whether it is possible to reduce cost *during evaluation* when the unary expression is the identity function.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that Eigen is an expression template library, therefore any unary expression does not immediately evaluate. Evaluation, or the loop over the vectors, is triggered when the assignment occurs, that is by `operator=`. Therefore passing an identity functor to `unaryExpr` will cost nothing.

Comment: But it will come with a cost when evaluated (eg. when an assignment occurs). It would also be possible to to avoid the cost completely with identity functions, my question was if that is implemented somehow.